# Executing raw sql in entity framework does not return result set

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using the following query. It returns 5 rows in a list but all the elements in the list are `null`.

```
public class TempClass
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string SNAME { get; set; }
    public string SAGE { get; set; }
}

var i = _dbContext.Database
                  .SqlQuery<TempClass>("select ID, NAME, AGE from eis_hierarchy")
                  .ToList();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try making the columns returned in the SQL query match the property names in the class you're trying to return:

```
var i = _dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<TempClass>("select ID as SID, NAME as SNAME, AGE as SAGE from eis_hierarchy")
    .ToList();
```